# Rename an app in Play.Google

Tags: android, google-play, rename

I have an app with lots of downloads called "SkypeGrandma". All my apps deal with the same project (remote elder care). SkypeGrandma is a poor choice of name and justly rejected in the Play.Google because it starts with "Skype".
Can I update this app and change its name to "Bla Bla Bla"? Ome would imagine that this is possible since they will never publish an app whose name begins with "Skype".

Now, here's the kicker. I already have "Bla Bla Bla" as an app I have unpublished.  Can I use this old  name. The advantage is that the name beginning with Skype has lots of downloads. They are really all part of the same project, It's not like I'm changing a popular fart app to a Calculus app and applying the downloads.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Getting things to work in the Play Store is a valid endeavour for programmers. But unlike programming is't non-deterministic and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the unpublished app name as long as you rename it something else first. google lets you change the names in the google play console very easily

Answer (score 1):

You can change your app name displayed on the Play Store in the Developer Console:

> Store listing > Title

You should also change the name of your app inside AndroidManifest.xml. Check the property `android:label` of the element `application`

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: thank you. Both answers were very helpful indeed.